# how can get the user name of the python script during excution

Tags: python, linux

Suppose there is a script sth.py

When i logged with 'root' account. type :

```
python sth.py
```

i want to get the result :  'root'

When type `sudo -u work python sth.py` , i want to get the result : 'work'

How to get it ?

Thank you~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import getpass
getpass.getuser()
```

Solutions using environment variables are generally not portable.

Answer (score 1):

On linux the environmental variables LOGNAME and USER should be set:

```
import os
print os.environ['LOGNAME']
```